# How to check all fields in 2 objects are equal using reflectionEquals?

Tags: java, string, junit, assert

I am writing a `JUnit` test and I want to test that **all the fields** in 2 objects are equal.

I have tried the following:

```
    @Test
    public void testPersonObjectsAreEqual(){
      
        Person expectedPerson = new Person("100100", "sampleName", "sampleAddress");
        Person actualPersonReturned = repository.getPersonById("100100");
        
        Assert.assertTrue(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(expectedPerson, actualPersonReturned));
    }
```

But the test is failing, even though the fields in the 2 objects are the same.

They are both have: `100100` , `sampleName` and `sampleAddress`

Comment: you could just override the equals method of your person class and then debug where it fails. and you should fix the typo  in line 5 :("100100); -> ("100100");

Comment: `EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals()` will try to equal all the attributes inside those given objects. You should pass the `sampleName` and `sampleAddress` to specify that you only need those attributes to be considered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you need to override the equals method in your class Person (returning true if the attributes of the Person object are all equal). For example:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (surname == null) {
            if (other.surname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

You can do it automatically with an IDE, the previous snippet was generated automatically with Eclipse.

Comment: Does this work for a nested structure ? I only added the 3 fields for simplicity, but I also have nested objects, i.e. Address object within the Person object?

Comment: Yes, but in that case the equals method should be overrided also in the 2nd level class (and 3rd, etc)

Comment: got it working when I added the equals method to the nested classes also

Comment: You should actually be very careful about overriding the equals method. While it will work in this case, it might cause harmful side-effects in other parts of your system.

Answer (score 3):

`EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals()` has many variations.
Consider to exclude the unwanted attributes. Then you can precisely compare 2 objects.

You can also use a simple `equals()` override in your particular class and do the same.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-

Answer (score 2):

The simplest/the most preferred way is to override `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in all the classes you assert on (including the nested classes) and use `Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual)`.

The reason why the comparison fails for 2 fields is because `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs)` is doing a shallow comparison and in your actual code `Person` has a reference to an `Address` instance, which does not have `equals()` implemented.

Comment: Ok, I am not familiar with doing this, what do I actualy need to put in the over ride method? I.e. If I wanted to check each of those 3 fields in my object?

Comment: Also, does this work for a nested structure ? I only added the 3 fields for simplicity, but I also have nested objects, i.e. Address object within the Person object?

Comment: I suspected that you have a nested object and your code is actually different than what you have provided, because what you have provided cannot fail.

Answer (score 0):

Write equals,hashCode method in Person class to decide the equality of objects

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a custom matcher for this

```
@Test
public void testPersonObjectsAreEqual(){

    Person expectedPerson = new Person("100100", "sampleName", "sampleAddress")
    Person actualPersonReturned = repository.getPersonById("100100");

    assertThat(actualPersonReturned, is(matchingPerson(expectedPerson)));
}

private Matcher<Person> matchingPerson(Person expected) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<Person>() {
        public boolean matchesSafely(Person actual) {
            return actual.getId().equals(expected.getId())
                && actual.getName().equals(expected.getName();
                && actual.getAddress().equals(expected.getAddress();
        }

        public void describeMismatchSafely(Person person, Description mismatchDescription) {
            mismatchDescription.appendText("give a meaningful message");
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: IMO this is way to complicated for such a simple task

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nice library called Unitils which logs very nicely as well with a in depth info what went wrong

```
User user1 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
User user2 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
assertReflectionEquals(user1, user2);
```

Easy to use and do not need to override the equals and hash methods.
This assertion loops over all fields in both objects and compares their values using reflection. For the above example, it will first compare both id field values, next both first field values and finally both last fields values.

http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin, you can use Mockito's matchers:

```
@Test
fun someEqualsTest(){
 
    val actual = ...
    val expected = ...

    assertTrue(ReflectionEquals(actual).matches(expected))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test using assertEquals instead of assertTrue

```
@Test
public void testPersonObjectsAreEqual(){

    Person expectedPerson = new Person("100100", "sampleName", "sampleAddress")
    Person actualPersonReturned = repository.getPersonById("100100);

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedPerson, actualPersonReturned);
}
```